# Function for future expected sales query won't run - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have this query which is a function for getting the expecting sales for any given future month.

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION get_expected_sales(month INT)
RETURNS DOUBLE(4, 2)

BEGIN
  DECLARE month INT;
  DECLARE total_sales_2015 INT;
  DECLARE total_sales_2016 INT;
  DECLARE total_sales_2017 INT;
  DECLARE expected_sales DOUBLE(5, 2);

  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO total_sales_2015
  FROM fss_Payment payTableRef
  WHERE MONTH(paydate)=month AND YEAR(paydate)=2015;

  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO total_sales_2016
  FROM fss_Payment payTableRef
  WHERE MONTH(paydate)=month AND YEAR(paydate)=2016;

  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO total_sales_2017
  FROM fss_Payment payTableRef
  WHERE MONTH(paydate)=month AND YEAR(paydate)=2017;

  SET expected_sales = ROUND((total_sales_2015+total_sales_2016+total_sales_2017)/3,2);

  RETURN expected_sales;

  END //

  DELIMITER;
```

The main errors I'm getting are: "Function already exists" and "Error in WHERE clause on Line 15"

Comment: You may have already created this function before and now you are trying to add it again. Add this line below the Delimiter declaration: `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_expected_sales`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already tried this and it doesn't work so I'm assuming it is something to do with my actual query?

Comment: These 3 queries can be simplified into this one: `SELECT ROUND(SUM(amount)/3,2) INTO expected_sales
  FROM fss_Payment 
  WHERE MONTH(paydate)=month AND YEAR(paydate) in (2015,2016,2017)`